# ValueError in For Loop when creating matplotlib chart from a subset of grouped values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My data source has changed and I'm having trouble updating the code that creates plots from grouped data. I am able to successfully plot a subset of the data, but I need to add a condition that will plot 2 subsets on the same chart. Is there a way I can structure my for/if/elif to make this work?

[This is what works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0Qf4.jpg)

However, treated_eye values contain both OD and OS and I need to plot them both on the same chart: when OD, I need to plot the *_od column values and when OS, I need to plot the *_os column values so I modfied my code and am getting a value error:

```
# plot for new data
for subject_group, sub_df in new_df.groupby(by='subject_group'):
    if new_df.treated_eye == 'OD':
        plt.plot(sub_df['visit_number'], sub_df['white_od'], marker='o', label=subject_group)
    elif new_df.treated_eye == 'OS':
        plt.plot(sub_df['visit_number'], sub_df['white_os'], marker='o', label=subject_group)

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)

# add a normal line at -65
# plt.ylim(ymin=-70, ymax=-30) # add ymax to make both color plots consistent
plt.xticks(range(0, new_od_df['visit_number'].max() + 1 , 1))

plt.xlabel('Visit (Months)')
plt.ylabel('Threshold (dB)')

# add a dashed green line and "normal"
plt.axhline(-65, color="green", linestyle='--', dashes=(5, 10)) #length of 5, space of 10
plt.text(13, -65, 'Normal', va='center', ha="left", bbox=dict(facecolor="w",alpha=0.5))


plt.title('RPGR-001: White FST (Treated Eye)')
plt.tight_layout()
# plt.savefig('output/rpgr_fst_white_teye.png')
```

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 # plot for new data
>         2 for subject_group, sub_df in new_df.groupby(by='subject_group'):
>   ----> 3     if new_df.treated_eye == 'OD':
>         4         plt.plot(sub_df['visit_number'], sub_df['white_od'], marker='o', label=subject_group)
>         5     elif new_df.treated_eye == 'OS':
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py
>   in **nonzero**(self)    1574         raise ValueError("The truth value
>   of a {0} is ambiguous. "    1575                          "Use
>   a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
>   -> 1576                          .format(self.**class**.**name**))    1577     1578     **bool** = **nonzero**
>
> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: I don't know beans about dataframes in python.  But since the problem is ValueError, and specifically that a "Series" can't be given a specific truth value, this makes me think the problem has to be with the `if ...elif` block.  The comparisons there can't work unless `new_df.treat_eye` is a single string and nothing else.  A list of strings, for instance, would cause big problems.  Is that what it is?  I would double check that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with `matplotlib` but in the `if` statements. `new_df.treated_eye` and `new_df.treated_eye` are columns of your DataFrame which contain more than one entries. When you do `if new_df.treated_eye == 'OD'`, you are treating `new_df.treated_eye` just as a variable when it is a list. Since you want to plot when all the elements fulfill this condition, you need to use `all()`

Therefore, try the following

```
for subject_group, sub_df in new_df.groupby(by='subject_group'):
    if all(new_df.treated_eye == 'OD'):
        plt.plot(sub_df['visit_number'], sub_df['white_od'], marker='o', label=subject_group)
    elif all(new_df.treated_eye == 'OS'):
        plt.plot(sub_df['visit_number'], sub_df['white_os'], marker='o', label=subject_group)
```

Comment: Thank you.  With that update I don't get an error, but it also doesn't plot anything so the plot is blank or empty.

Comment: Thank you.  Apparently, I need to use `any()` as that method returns `TRUE` with OS or OD.  Using `all()` didn't plot any values.

Comment: This code results in a logical error.  If I use `any()`, the `plt` executes for the `if` statement as expected, but for the `elif` condition I get the same result.  I get a blank plot if I use `all()`.  What is wrong with my `if` statement within the `for` loop?